# Unable to use "HelveticaLtEx" font in Flex project

Tags: apache-flex

Unable to use "HelveticaLtEx" font.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                width="100%" height="100%" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="12"
                xmlns:ilog="http://www.ilog.com/2007/ilog/flex"       
                xmlns:local="c7.views.apps.calendar.*"
                backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">      
    <mx:Style>
        @font-face {
            src:url("assets/cloud_main/font/HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtEx.otf");
            fontFamily: HelveticaLtEx;          
        }
        .dateStyle{ 
            font-family: "HelveticaLtEx";
            fontSize: 18;       
        }
    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:VBox>
            <mx:Label text="testing testing testing" styleName="dateStyle"/>            
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Canvas>


</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **bold** and *italics* properties must match the properties of the font itself.

Try these styles and see what happens :

```
    .dateStyle{ 
        font-family: "HelveticaLtEx";
        fontSize: 18; 
        fontWeight:bold;      
    }
```

Or :

```
   .dateStyle{ 
        font-family: "HelveticaLtEx";
        fontSize: 18; 
        fontStyle:italic;      
    }
```

Or :

```
   .dateStyle{ 
        font-family: "HelveticaLtEx";
        fontSize: 18; 
        fontWeight:bold;    
        fontStyle:italic;  
    }
```

It will work for you, if not, let me know and we'll try something else...

Comment: They work, but if I remove/make it normal the fontWeight or fontStyle, the text again disappears. How, can I still have the text visible if its normal style or weight.

Comment: you have to embed the version of the font that is normal weight (you're embedding a bold font, so the style has to be bold to see it! otherwise the player is going "dude, i dont have a normal version of this font, only bold!").  Make sense?   =)